# The effect of a Cayley transform on a Cartan subalgebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, lie-derivative

I'm trying to understand equation 6.65b from Knapp's 'Lie groups,' 2ed.

---

**Setup:** Let $\mathfrak{g}_0$ be a real semisimple Lie algebra with an involution $\theta$. Let $B$ be a bilinear, symmetric, non-degenerate, invariant, $\theta$-invariant form on $\mathfrak{g}_0$. Assume that $B_\theta(X,Y):= -B(X,\theta Y)$ is positive definite on $\mathfrak{g}_0$. We can decompose $\mathfrak{g}_0=\mathfrak{k}_0\oplus\mathfrak{p}_0$ as $\pm 1$ eigenspaces for $\theta$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the complexification $\mathfrak{g}_0\otimes \mathbb{C}$, and by extension of scalars, extend $B$ and $\theta$ to $\mathfrak{g}$. We extend $B_\theta$ to a Hermitian inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$ by $B_\theta(X,Y):=-B(X,\theta\bar{Y})$.

Say $\mathfrak{h}_0 \subset \mathfrak{g}_0$ is a "Cartan subalgebra". That is, say that $\mathfrak{h}:=\mathfrak{h}_0 \otimes \mathbb{C} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ is a Cartan subalgebra. Assume that $\mathfrak{h}_0$ is $\theta$-stable so that we can write $\mathfrak{h}_0 = \mathfrak{a}_0 \oplus \mathfrak{t}_0$ where the components are in $\mathfrak{p}_0$ and $\mathfrak{k}_0$ respectively.
Let $\Delta:= \Delta(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{h}) \subset \text{Hom}_\mathbb{C}(\mathfrak{h}, \mathbb{C})$ be the set of roots. Recall, the roots are positive on $\mathfrak{a}_0 \oplus i\mathfrak{t}_0$ and that $B$ is positive definite here. We can thus transfer to an inner product on $V:=\text{span}_\mathbb{R} \Delta$ via the isomorphism $ \mathfrak{a}_0 \oplus i\mathfrak{t}_0 \to V;\ H \mapsto B(H, \cdot)$. This we denote by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and the norm we denote by $|\cdot|$.

Assume we have a root $\beta \in \Delta$ which is "imaginary". That is, it vanishes on $\mathfrak{a}_0$. This shows that the $\beta$-eigenspace satisfies $\theta \mathfrak{g}_\beta = \mathfrak{g}_\beta$ so that $\mathfrak{g}_\beta$ is contained in either $\mathfrak{p}:= \mathfrak{p}_0 \otimes \mathbb{C}$ or in $\mathfrak{k}:= \mathfrak{k}_0\otimes \mathbb{C}$.
Assume that $\beta$ is "non-compact", that is, the eigenspace $\mathfrak{g}_\beta$ is contained in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Take any nonzero $E_\beta \in \mathfrak{g}_\beta$. The fact that $\beta$ is imaginary implies that $\overline{E}_\beta \in \mathfrak{g}_{-\beta}$. We can also assume that $B(E_\beta,\overline{E}_\beta) = 2 |\beta|^{-2}$ since we have
$$
0 < B_\theta(E_\beta, E_\beta) = - B(E_\beta, \theta \overline{E}_\beta) = B(E_\beta, \overline{E}_\beta).
$$
If we define $H_\beta$ by the property $\beta(H) = B(H, H_\beta)\ \ \forall H \in \mathfrak{h}$ and $H'_\beta:= 2|\beta|^{-2} H_\beta$, we see that $[E_\beta, \overline{E}_\beta] = H'_\beta$ so that the triple $H'_\beta, E_\beta, \overline{E}_\beta$ generates a subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Now define the operator
$$
c_\beta := \exp ad_{\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\overline{E}_\beta - E_\beta\right)} \in \text{Aut} \left(\mathfrak{g}\right)
$$
which can be seen to satisfy
\begin{equation}\label{use}\tag{1}
c_\beta\left(H'_\beta\right) = E_\beta + \overline{E}_\beta.
\end{equation}

---

**Question:** How do I see from \eqref{use} the identity
\begin{equation}\label{ques}\tag{2}
\mathfrak{g}_0 \cap c_\beta(\mathfrak{h}) = \text{ker}\left(\beta|_\mathfrak{h_0}\right)
\oplus \mathbb{R} \left(E_\beta + \overline{E}_\beta\right).
\end{equation}

**Attempt:** The definition of $c_\beta$ and the fact that $[\overline{E}_\beta - E_\beta, H] = 0$ for every $H\in \ker(\beta)$ shows that $\ker\left(\beta|_\mathfrak{h_0}\right) \subset \mathfrak{g}_0 \cap c_\beta(\mathfrak{h})$. And equation \eqref{use} shows that
$\mathbb{R} \left(E_\beta + \overline{E}_\beta\right) \subset \mathfrak{g}_0 \cap c_\beta(\mathfrak{h})$.

It remains to show L.H.S $\subset$ R.H.S in \eqref{ques} which I'm unable to do. I was trying to show that the (real) dimension of the L.H.S is the same as the (real) dimension of $\mathfrak{h}_0$ which would suffice.

Please send help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er, I guess one can write
$$
\mathfrak{h}_0 = \mathbb{R}(iH_\beta') \oplus \text{ker}(\beta|_{\mathfrak{h}_0})\ \text{ so that }\ 
\mathfrak{h}= \mathbb{C}(iH'_\beta) \oplus\mathbb{C}\cdot\text{ker}(\beta|_{\mathfrak{h}_0}).
$$
Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathfrak{g}_0\cap c_\beta(\mathfrak{h}) &= \mathfrak{g}_0 \cap \left(\mathbb{C}\left(\overline{E}_\beta + E_\beta\right) \oplus \mathbb{C}\cdot \text{ker}(\beta|_{\mathfrak{h}_0})\right) \\
&= \mathfrak{g}_0\cap \mathbb{C}\cdot\left(\left(\overline{E}_\beta + E_\beta\right) \oplus \text{ker}(\beta|_{\mathfrak{h}_0})\right) \\
&= \mathbb{R}\left(\overline{E}_\beta + E_\beta\right) \oplus \text{ker}(\beta|_{\mathfrak{h}_0}).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
wefnawiebv;gwbeiwebg!